# How can I call a function in one class from another class? Rollingcurl

Tags: php, function, class, curl

I use Rollingcurl to crawl various pages.

Rollingcurl: https://github.com/LionsAd/rolling-curl

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require "RollingCurl.php";
require "tmdb_class.php";
$tmdb = new Tmdb;

if (isset($_GET['action']) || isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action'] : $_POST['action'];
} else {
    $action = "";
}

echo "  Test<br /><br />";


/*function most_popular($response, $info)
{

    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //disable libxml errors

    if (!empty($response)) {
        //if any html is actually returned

        $doc->loadHTML($response);
        libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

        //get all the h2's with an id
        $row   = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'lister-item-image') and contains(@class, 'float-left')]/a/@href");
        $nexts = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@class, 'lister-page-next') and contains(@class, 'next-page')]");
        $names   = $xpath->query('//img[@class="loadlate"]');

        foreach ($nexts as $next) {
            echo "Next URL: " . $next->getAttribute('href') . "<br/>";
        }

        foreach ($names as $name) {
            echo "Release Name: " . $name->getAttribute('alt') . "<br/>";
        }

        if ($row->length > 0) {
            foreach ($row as $row) {
                echo $doc->saveHtml($row) . "<br/>";
            }
        }

    }
}*/

if ($action == "most_popular") {

    if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
        $link = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature,tv_movie&release_date=,".$_GET['date'];
    } else {
        $link = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature,tv_movie&release_date=,2018";
    }

    $urls            = array($link);
    $rc              = new RollingCurl("most_popular");
    $rc->window_size = 20;
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $request = new RollingCurlRequest($url);
        $rc->add($request);
    }
    $stream = $rc->execute();
}
```

In a simple way, the function "most_popular" can of course be called. But I want to build and call my own class for some functions.

If the function "most_popular" is in my class, it is not so easy to call it:

My Class:

```
<?php

class Tmdb
{


    public function __construct()
    {
      /* */
    }

    // SEARCH
    public function most_popular($response, $info)
    {

        $doc = new DOMDocument();

        libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //disable libxml errors

        if (!empty($response)) {
            //if any html is actually returned

            $doc->loadHTML($response);
            libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

            $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

            //get all the h2's with an id
            $row   = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'lister-item-image') and contains(@class, 'float-left')]/a/@href");
            $nexts = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@class, 'lister-page-next') and contains(@class, 'next-page')]");
            $names = $xpath->query('//img[@class="loadlate"]');

            foreach ($nexts as $next) {
                echo "Next URL: " . $next->getAttribute('href') . "<br/>";
            }

            foreach ($names as $name) {
                echo "Release Name: " . $name->getAttribute('alt') . "<br/>";
            }

            if ($row->length > 0) {
                foreach ($row as $row) {
                    echo $doc->saveHtml($row) . "<br/>";
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how this works?

This isn't working:

```
$rc              = new RollingCurl($tmdb->most_popular);
```

or

```
$rc              = new RollingCurl($tmdb->most_popular());
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The question's title must also be in English.

Comment: Sorry, Edit. Thank you!

Comment: Why is the function definition commented out in the first code block?

Comment: It was just a test. If the function is directly in the file, I can call it.

But I want to outsource these and other functions in my own class. But I don't know how to call the function with rollingcurl.

Rollingcurl requires the name of the function.

In a class the function must be addressed with $tmdb->function_name. Therefore my question, how can I call this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use an object method as a callback, you make an array containing the object and the method name.

```
$rc = new RollingCurl([$tmdb, 'most_popular']);
```

Comment: WOW! This works without any problems. I would like to thank you very much.